# How do I clear an "if" condition?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to clear an "if" condition and how to fix the `result = print(x)` part of my code. I'm trying to create a little search code based on the variable `data`, but I can't figure a few things out:

```
import time

def start():
    data = ["Lucas_Miguel", "João_Batista", "Rafael_Gomes", "Bruna_Santos", "Lucas_Denilson"]
    print("1" + " - Check Name")
    print("2" + " - Register a New Name")
    option = input("Choose an option: ")
    if option == "1":
        def other():
            name = input("Type the first name: ")
            for x in data:
                if name in x:
                    result = print(x)
                    while True:
                        print("Yes " "or " "No")
                        confirm = input("Is the name you want in the options?: ")
                        if confirm == "Yes":
                            break
                        if confirm == "No":
                            print("Yes", " or", " No")
                            try_again = input("Do you want to write again?: ")
                            if try_again == "Yes":
                                return other()
        other()
    else:
        print("Option not available")
        time.sleep(1)
        return start()
start()
```

The first problem is in the `result = print(x)` part. It works, but when the answer is more than one name, only the first one appear and I don't know how to fix it.

The second problem is in the "`confirm = input`" part. Basically, if the person answered with "No", when they go back, the answer will still be saved and the input will run twice, the first time with the saved answer and the second with the new answer. So I want to be able to clear that before the person answer it again.

Comment: Being new is fine, but please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. Note the requirement to ask a single-well scoped question.

Comment: What do you mean by "clearing" an `if` condition?

Answer (score 2):

I have some suggestions to improve your code:

- Split the `other` into its own function
- Try to use more accurate variable names
- As much as you can - avoid having multiple for loops happening at the same time
- Have a look at list comprehension it would help a lot in this case
- Think about whether a variable really belongs in a function or not like `data`

This code should do what you want - and implements the improvements as suggested above

```
import time

data = ["Lucas_Miguel", "João_Batista", "Rafael_Gomes", "Bruna_Santos", "Lucas_Denilson"]


def other():
    name_input = input("Type the first name: ")

    matches = [name for name in data if name_input in name]
    if len(matches) == 0:
        print ("No matches")
    for name in matches:
        print(name)
        while True:
            print("Yes " "or " "No")
            confirm = input("Is the name you want in the options?: ")
            if confirm == "Yes":
                break
            if confirm == "No":
                print("Yes", " or", " No")
                try_again = input("Do you want to write again?: ")
                if try_again == "Yes":
                    return other()
                else:
                    return
            

def start():
    print("1" + " - Check Name")
    print("2" + " - Register a New Name")
    option = input("Choose an option: ")
    if option == "1":
        other()
    else:
        print("Option not available")
        time.sleep(1)
        return start()

start()
```

Comment: A ‘return’ might be more suitable than my flag method as suggested by habrewning

Comment: Yes, you should remove the flag variable and immediately return.
People normally say that directly returning is bad style. But having 4 extra lines of code and the complicated indentation is also not so optimal. Returning is just easier in this case.
In your case returning is even the better option because you use recursion and with the return statement it looks like tail recursion. If you use recursion then such functional programming concepts are a good option.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem will be solved when you remove 8 spaces before `while True:`.

The second problem will be solved when you add `return` (without arguments) one line below `return other()` at the indentation level of `if try_again == "Yes":`

Everybody can see that you are just learning Python. You don't have to apologize if you think, your code is "ugly or weird". We all started with such small exercises.